# Installing an npm module as a devDependency of itself

Tags: node.js, npm

Let's say I've made a TDD tool called **foo**, and I want to use **foo v1** to help me develop **foo v2**.

But when I `npm install --save-dev foo@^1.0.0`, npm says "Refusing to install foo as a dependency of itself".

1. Why does npm refuse to do this?
2. What can I do instead?

Workarounds I've got so far (and why they're not good enough):

- **Workaround 1:** just require the relevant script directly using a relative require, e.g. `require('../lib')` (this is how [mocha does it](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/test/suite.js), and it's how I've been doing it so far).

  - **but** if you're working on a new version of your module, adding features, perhaps even removing old features, then you're constantly having to alter not just the content of your tests but also their *format*, because you're actually using the thing you're working on to test the thing you're working on. If it breaks, you have to fix it in the dark with no tests to guide you. It would be much better to use the *settled* v1 API for tdd-ing the new v2 API.
- **Workaround 2:** publish a duplicate of your module to npm under a different name, like "foo-clone". (Then you can just install foo-clone as a devDependency of foo.)

  - **but** that seems messy and a misuse of npm. Anyway, if installing an exact clone would work, then what would be the harm in npm allowing me to install [an old version of] foo as a devDependency of foo?

Comment: Anything commonly used between foo v1 and foo v2 can be branched out in its own npm module and referenced in both versions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better alternative to your **Workaround 2**.

---

Let's assume that you'll only need this dependency on early stage of development. So, before publishing first production-ready version you'll get rid of it, e.g. by adopting `mocha` solution (using current stable version to test itself).

In this case, instead of publishing duplicate package you could temporary rename your package (i.e. postfix it with `-dev`).

To guarantee that this renamed package will not be published, you could also add [`private` flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#private).

So, your dev package.json will look something like:

```json
{
  "name": "mytdd-dev",
  "version": "2.0.0-dev",
  "private": true,
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "mytdd": "1.x.x",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Then, when your package will be ready for the first release, you'll remove all `-dev` postfixes, `private` flag and dev dependency on previous version.

The only problem with this solution is that you won't be able to publish early dev versions of your TDD tool to npm (as long as you'll depend on previous version).

---

> if installing an exact clone would work, then what would be the harm in npm allowing me to install [an old version of] foo as a devDependency of foo

I think it's a safety precautions against circular dependencies.

If you believe that npm should make an exception for `devDependencies` here, which sounds reasonable to me, then you should post your suggestion to [`npm` issues tracker](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues).

Comment: "I think it's a safety precautions against circular dependencies." But if it's a devDependency then it could not be circular.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think the problem you identified is bigger than you suggest. I would have to make all those changes (name, remove private flag, dependency) every time I want to push *any* future version out, and then revert those changes to continue working on the next patch. Not just for early dev versions, but for all future releases. Lots of opportunities for human error. Plus it rules out running my tests automatically on prepublish, which I think is a crucial safety check. It sounds like pushing a clone to npm would be much easier.

Comment: @callum I assumed that you'll only need this dependency on early stage of development, so you'll get rid of it before publishing first production-ready version (most likely, use current stable version instead, like `mocha` do). If my assumption is incorrect, then my suggestion won't work for you.

Comment: And if you believe that `npm` should make an exception for `devDependencies` here, then you should post your suggestion to [`npm` issues tracker](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues).

Comment: @callum added those comments to my answer